# React Native DatePicker Display Value

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am new to react native and i am trying to make a date picker for birthday selection for the users on a personal information page. And I use DatePicker library for that. When user selects and clicks on update button with the post request, I will display the value from get request. My date state is equal to today's date as initial value. The library has its own props for onChange, it changes and selects but when i try to display the state, it always shows the initial date as today's date. But i want to display the selected date. What is my error here ? Below is my code.

```
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';
import moment from 'moment';

const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState(new Date());
const [birthdayIsOpen, setBirthdayIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
const formattedBirthday = moment(birthday).format('YYYY-MM-DD');


 const onUpdate = () => {
      const rawUserData = {
        name: userName,
        email,
        gender,
        education,
        birthday: formattedBirthday,
      };
      const processedUserData = {};
      for (const key in rawUserData) {
        if (rawUserData[key]) {
          processedUserData[key] = rawUserData[key];
        }
      }
      updateUser(processedUserData);
    }
  };


 <Button
   title=""
   onPress={() => setBirthdayIsOpen(true)}
   containerStyle={styles.dateButton}>
   <Text style={styles.dateButtonText}>
     {birthday === new Date() ? 'Select Your Birthday' : formattedBirthday}
   </Text>
 </Button>

 <DatePicker
   date={birthday}
   onDateChange={() => setBirthday(birthday)}
   mode="date"
   modal
   androidVariant="nativeAndroid"
   open={birthdayIsOpen}
   onConfirm={date => {
     setBirthdayIsOpen(false);
     setBirthday(date);
   }}
   onCancel={() => {
     setBirthdayIsOpen(false);
   }}
   textColor="gray"
 />
```

Comment: can you show me the output selected date?

Comment: for example i choose a date from calendar. it reflects on the input and updates successfully and sends to the api, returns success message but when i return to the page, i always see the today's date, not the selected date.@Sumit_VE